# Apple Mail generating Mail[378]: No worthy mechs found. What is it?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I know it's Apple mail because the PID of the running Mail is 378

```
378 ??        44:44.93 /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail -psn_0_28679
```

In the Syslog file I'm getting is:

```
Mail[378]: No worthy mechs found
```

Does anyone have any idea why this shows, or what this is.

I'm running postfix and dovecot on 10.10.3

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447316/mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite-postfix-sasl-authentication-failed

Comment: Yes I saw that. I have relay host correct, and salsa_passwd correct, Still showing "no worthy mechs found" Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem (on a system that was NOT running postfix) by changing the authentication method on one email account from Password to MD5 Challenge-Response.